# Access 2007 won't open accdb file unless it's renamed

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have some programs written in VB6 which use a 30MB Access 2007 data file named BidBase.accdb. I have been able to open this file in Access 2007 for years, but now when I try, Access says "The document 'BidBase.accdb' caused a serious error the last time it was opened."

Here's where it gets strange:

If I rename the file to anything else, such as BidBase1.accdb, Access will open it.
If I copy the same file to another directory Access will open it.
My VB6 programs which use this file still open it and work with it okay.
My PC is setup to make daily backups of my VB6 projects to an external hard drive.
Opening the same file in one of those backup directories works, but if I copy that file to the root directory of that drive, it doesn't work. But on my internal drive, it's just the opposite - it won't load from in my VB6 directory but will load when copied to C:.

I don't have to open it with Access very often. I recently got a new PC on which I installed Access from the original disc, and that's where I first got the error, but when I went back to the old PC, the same thing happens, so it would not seem to be a problem with my PC. In other words, it's hard to imagine that reinstalling Access or any other potential solutions specific to this PC would help.

In 40 years of working with PCs, this is the most bizarre, inexplicable thing I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Backup your file
2. Rename the file
3. Open the file in Access
4. "Save as" the file naming it BidBase.accdb
5. Close Access
6. Open BidBase.accdb

Comment: Weird. Try to run a _repair_ of the Office installation.

Comment: As I mentioned, it does this on two different machines with Access installed 5+ years apart, and it never had a problem on the old machine until recently.

Comment: Oh. Then I would rename the file and move on.

Comment: Is there a variable in the code name _BidBase_? That could create a conflict of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I tried loading it under a different name but when I did a Save-As, it gave me the same error message as when I tried to open it, even though the file is not present by that name any more, indicating that Access is keeping track of the problem file by name, but still doesn't explain why it flagged the file under that name but not the same file under other names.

But the next oddity is that it did save it under the name BidBase.accdb, but that file is only 5MB while the original is 31MB. I've compared the two files and the contents appear to be the same.

And now that my attention has been drawn to that, I realize that the largest table in the database has about 10k records, meaning that each record in the 31MB DB would have 3,100 bytes, which isn't remotely possible.

I also tried using the newly saved file under the old name in my programs and they work, but then they also worked with the old file under the old name when Access wouldn't.

So I'll keep working with the new file for a while to make sure it's okay, but this is all  still a bizarre mystery to me.